# RNGCryptoServiceProvider and Rfc2898DeriveBytes

Tags: c#, encryption

Does it make sense to run a encryption key (2048 bit) generated with the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` through `Rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes()` or is `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` more geared toward generating encryption keys from shorter keys like passphrases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have something suitable for a key, which it appears you have, why would you use it to generate another key? Personally I don't see any benefit putting it through derived bytes as you already have a cryptographically secure random number.

Answer (score 4):

`Rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes()` is mainly used for getting a key of the right size with your encryption chipper size. If you're sure that your key is secure this is not needed (and of course if the key sizes match). If it's a user input (i.e. a passkey), than definitely use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class to derive a proper key (or use hashing with salt).